# Как можно оптимизировать код ниже либо сделать его чище?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Игра в слова.
Есть 2 цикла for, но они играют разные роли. 1-ый составляет список слов для игры, 2-ой включает слова, которые ещё не использовались.

```
import random

my_file = (open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/слова.txt'))
text = my_file.read()
my_file.close()
words = []
available_words = list(words)
for word in text.split():
    words.append(word)
    available_words = list(words)
    random.shuffle(available_words)
    anyword = available_words.pop()
print("Рандомное слово " + anyword)


def playing(anyword):
    game_is_over = False
    while not game_is_over:
        mess = input()
        if len(mess) != 0:
            if anyword[-1] == "ъ" or anyword[-1] == "ь" or anyword[-1] == "ы":
                if anyword[-2] == mess.lower()[0]:
                    print(anyword)
                    for candidant in available_words:
                        if candidant.lower()[0] == mess.lower()[-1]:
                            anyword = candidant
                            print(anyword)
                            available_words.remove(candidant)
                            break
                else:
                    print(
                        "Неверно, слово должно начинаться с буквы " + anyword[-2])
            elif mess.lower()[0] != anyword.lower()[-1]:
                print(
                    "Неверно, слово должно начинаться с буквы " + anyword[-1])
            else:
                for candidant in available_words:
                    if candidant.lower()[0] == mess.lower()[-1]:
                        anyword = candidant
                        print(anyword)
                        available_words.remove(candidant)
                        break
                    elif mess.lower()[-1] == "ъ" or mess.lower()[-1] == "ь" or mess.lower()[-1] == "ы":
                        if candidant[0].lower() == mess[-2].lower():
                            anyword = candidant
                            print(anyword)
                            available_words.remove(candidant)
                            break
                else:
                    print("Словарный запас был иссечён, схожу за новой порцией.")
                    game_is_over = True
        else:
            print("Введите слово")


playing(anyword)
```

Comment: ну вот прям первое что в голову приходит `anyword[-1] == "ъ" or anyword[-1] == "ь" or anyword[-1] == "ы"` -> `anyword[-1] in ["ъ", "ь", "ы"]`

Comment: `if len(mess) != 0` -> `if mess`

Comment: Там много что есть оптимизировать подобного. Поставьте PyCharm он вам все кейсы подсветит и советов надает.

Comment: `"Словарный запас был иссечён, схожу за новой порцией."` -> `"Словарный запас был ИСЧЕРПАН, схожу за новой порцией."` Если плагин для проверки поставить для русского языка то PyCharm и это исправит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic